# Protobuf 3.0 Any Type pack/unpack

Tags: protocol-buffers, pack, unpack, any

I would like to know how to transform a Protobuf **Any** Type to the original Protobuf message type and vice versa. In Java from Message to Any is easy:

```
Any.Builder anyBuilder = Any.newBuilder().mergeFrom(protoMess.build());
```

But how can I parse that **Any** back to the originial message (e.g. to the type of "protoMess")? I could probably parse everything on a stream just to read it back in, but that's not what I want. I want to have some transformation like this:

```
ProtoMess.MessData.Builder protoMessBuilder = (ProtoMess.MessData.Builder) transformToMessageBuilder(anyBuilder)
```

How can I achieve that? Is it already implemented for Java? The [Protobuf Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) says there were pack and unpack methods, but there are none in Java. 
Thank you in Advance :)

Answer (score 36):

The answer might be a bit late but maybe this still helps someone.

In the current version of Protocol Buffers 3 `pack` and `unpack` are [available in Java](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#any).

In your example packing can be done like:

```java
Any anyMessage = Any.pack(protoMess.build()));
```

And unpacking like:

```java
ProtoMess protoMess = anyMessage.unpack(ProtoMess.class);
```

---

Here is also a full example for handling Protocol Buffers messages with nested `Any` messages:

## ProtocolBuffers Files

A simple Protocol Buffers file with a nested `Any` message could look like:

```java
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message ParentMessage {
  string text = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any childMessage = 2;
}
```

A possible nested message could then be:

```java
syntax = "proto3";

message ChildMessage {
  string text = 1;
}
```

## Packing

To build the full message the following function can be used:

```java
public ParentMessage createMessage() {
    // Create child message
    ChildMessage.Builder childMessageBuilder = ChildMessage.newBuilder();
    childMessageBuilder.setText("Child Text");
    // Create parent message
    ParentMessage.Builder parentMessageBuilder = ParentMessage.newBuilder();
    parentMessageBuilder.setText("Parent Text");
    parentMessageBuilder.setChildMessage(Any.pack(childMessageBuilder.build()));
    // Return message
    return parentMessageBuilder.build();
}
```

## Unpacking

To read the child message from the parent message the following function can be used:

```java
public ChildMessage readChildMessage(ParentMessage parentMessage) {
    try {
        return parentMessage.getChildMessage().unpack(ChildMessage.class);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If your packed messages can have different Types, you can read out the `typeUrl` and use reflection to unpack the message. Assuming you have the child messages `ChildMessage1` and `ChildMessage2` you can do the following:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Message readChildMessage(ParentMessage parentMessage) {
    try {
        Any childMessage = parentMessage.getChildMessage();
        String clazzName = childMessage.getTypeUrl().split("/")[1];
        String clazzPackage = String.format("package.%s", clazzName);
        Class<Message> clazz = (Class<Message>) Class.forName(clazzPackage);
        return childMessage.unpack(clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

For further processing, you could determine the type of the message with `instanceof`, which is not very efficient. If you want to get a message of a certain type, you should compare the `typeUrl` directly:

```java
public ChildMessage1 readChildMessage(ParentMessage parentMessage) {
    try {
        Any childMessage = parentMessage.getChildMessage();
        String clazzName = childMessage.getTypeUrl().split("/")[1];
        if (clazzName.equals("ChildMessage1")) {
            return childMessage.unpack("ChildMessage1.class");
        }
        return null
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way than this `readChildMessage`? What if I there are dozens of different messages that could come in? Just add in new `try-catch` blocks? Even `switch-case` and the like is absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: Good question, I forgot to add that you can get the name of the packed message as `typeURL`. This allows to unpack any message via reflection or directly decide what to do with the message. I added two examples to my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: Great! It helped me!

Comment: childMessage.getTypeUrl().split("/")[1]; won't give the java package name right? It will give the proto package and hence will not work.

Comment: @AdityaJoshee that's correct. Ideally, I'd like to get the canonical name of the class, but you get the package of the proto files. That's quite annoying.

Comment: My problem is that I have hundred of possible types and I cannot really write a (X == Y)-like condition for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add information in case someone has the same problem ... Currently to unpack you have to do (c# .netcore 3.1 Google.Protobuf 3.11.4)

```
Foo myobject = anyMessage.Unpack<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but it still came up when I was looking for the answer. Using @sundance answer I had to answer do this a little differently. The problem being that the actual message was a subclass of the actual class. So it required a $.

```
    for(Any x : in.getDetailsList()){
            try{
                String clazzName = x.getTypeUrl().split("/")[1];
                String[] split_name = clazzName.split("\\.");
                String nameClass = String.join(".", Arrays.copyOfRange(split_name, 0, split_name.length - 1)) + "$" + split_name[split_name.length-1];
                Class<Message> clazz = (Class<Message>) Class.forName(nameClass);

                System.out.println(x.unpack(clazz));

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

With this being the definition of my proto messages

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    package cb_grpc.msg.Main;

    service QueryService {
        rpc anyService (AnyID) returns (QueryResponse) {}
    }

    enum Buckets {
        main = 0;
        txn = 1;
        hxn = 2;
       }

    message QueryResponse{
        string content = 1;
        string code = 2;
    }

    message AnyID {
        Buckets bucket = 1;
        string docID = 2;
        repeated google.protobuf.Any details = 3;
    }
```

and

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    package org.querc.cb_grpc.msg.database;

    option java_package = "org.querc.cb_grpc.msg";
    option java_outer_classname = "database";

    message TxnLog {
        string doc_id = 1;
        repeated string changes = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in Android Java on my project as a pack function:

```
String name = message.getClass().getSimpleName();
String packageName = message.getClass().getPackage().getName();   //needs to be the same as your proto package
String fullName = packageName + '.'+ name;
String typeURL = GetTypeUrl(fullName);
    
Any any = Any.newBuilder()
            .setValue(message.toByteString())
            .setTypeUrl(typeURL)
            .build();

private String GetTypeUrl(String fullName) {
    String prefix = "type.googleapis.com";
   return prefix + "/" + fullName;
}
```